# Having trouble applying BufferedReader into Constructor of Java Class

Tags: java, android, gps, bufferedreader

I've been working on an android app that requires GPS coordinates and uses a 2d array to hold coordinates between [0][0] and [1024][512]. As of right now I have the main_activity create the BufferedReader, then pass it through a CoordinatesHandler Class that I created, which would filter through a text file and split the text coordinates and store them as integers in the 2d array. Although I am having trouble passing the BufferedReader through the constructor. Thanks for the help.

here is the CoordinatesHandler Class;

```
public class CoordinatesHandler{
    Integer[][] CoordinatesValue = new Integer[1024][512];

    public void CoordinatesHandler(BufferedReader reader){
        String line;

        while(true){
            int y= 0;
            try {
                line = reader.readLine();
                line.trim();
                String splitCords[] = line.split("\\s+");
                if (!line.contains("#") && line != null) {
                    for (int x = 0; x <= 1024; x++) {
                        CoordinatesValue[x][y] = Integer.parseInt(splitCords[x]);
                        Log.d(Integer.toString(x),Integer.toString(y));
                    }
                }else{break;}
            }catch(IOException e){Log.d("error", "IO Exception");}
            y++;
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the section where I implement this in the main_activity, *note(the readIt method is one of multiply methods supplied to android developers to download and read text files off the web)*:

```
public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));

        new CoordinatesHandler(reader);

        return "hello";
    }
```

The issue is that the compiler doesn't like "new CoordinatesHandler(reader)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructor should not have return type. Remove the return type "void" from the constructor and compile.